# Differences between ItemizedOverlay and Overlay class

Tags: android, android-mapview

Can someone tell my when to use Overlay or when to use ItemizedOverlay class!

What are differences between this two classes?

Draw methods do the same thing?

Can I use only ItemizedOverlay  class in my project or I must use and Overlay as base class!

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Overlay` is a general overlay. `ItemizedOverlay` is a subclass that makes it easier to create an overlay that is a discrete series of marked points on the map. So, if you are trying to show a bus route, or shade a region, or something like that, `Overlay` is the class you want. If you are trying to show a collection of restaurants, or churches, or whatever, `ItemizedOverlay` works.

Note, though, that `ItemizedOverlay` is designed for modest numbers of points (e.g., dozens). If you have a large number of points, you may need to create your own `Overlay` just for performance reasons.

Comment: CommonsWare, thanks for your help

I want to draw route, but also on this route I want to add draggable markers. 

Every line between two points should I put in different Overlay Item ?? Can you please give me idea

Comment: @Jovan: you will probably need two overlays, one `Overlay` for the route and one `ItemizedOverlay` for the markers. Here is a project demonstrating drag-and-drop markers: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/

Comment: What would be the equivalent of ItemzedOverlay in v2 of maps?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Just adding a series of markers --  no overlays required. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Markers

Comment: Thanks, I am having trouble with your project.  Opened an issue on GitHub.